# can anyone show an example of using animations programmatically via Aframe i.e. create and change properites via javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe

The following code does not produce any animation.  I want to use the bottom script tag to programmatically create and change animations.  thanks for the help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TANACH-CHUNKS</title>
<meta name="description" content="Cursor - A-Frame">
<script src="js/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene id = "sceneEl">   
<a-entity
position="0 -1.5 2.5"
>
<a-camera
id="camera"
keyboard-controls="enabled: true"
wasd-controls="acceleration: 10; enabled: false; adAxis:x"
>
<a-entity 
cursor="rayOrigin: mouse; fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500" 
id="cursor1"
position="0 0 -1"
geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.001; radiusOuter: 0.01"
material="color: blue; shader: flat"
>
</a-entity>
</a-camera>
</a-entity>
</a-entity>             
<a-entity id="box" geometry="primitive: box" material="color: red" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 30 0"
animation__mouseup="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: red; to: blue; startEvents: mouseup; dur: 5000"
animation__mouseup="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: blue; to: red; startEvents: mouseup; dur: 5000"
>
</a-entity> 
<script>
box.setAttribute("animation","property: position; to: 2 2 0; dur: 2000;");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share more details like you can more lines of code or scenario where you are using or output screenshot and so...

Answer (score 1):

Your animation property code works as expected, but other errors (namely, an extraneous `</a-entity>` tag in the middle and missing tags at the end) prevent it from compiling.  Here is the same code cleaned up, which works for me (assuming your path to aframe.min.js is correct):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TANACH-CHUNKS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Cursor - A-Frame" />
    <script src="js/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene id="sceneEl">
      <a-entity position="0 -1.5 2.5">
        <a-camera
          id="camera"
          keyboard-controls="enabled: true"
          wasd-controls="acceleration: 10; enabled: false; adAxis:x"
        >
          <a-entity
            cursor="rayOrigin: mouse; fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
            id="cursor1"
            position="0 0 -1"
            geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.001; radiusOuter: 0.01"
            material="color: blue; shader: flat"
          ></a-entity>
        </a-camera>
      </a-entity>
      <a-entity
        id="box"
        geometry="primitive: box"
        material="color: red"
        position="0 0 0"
        rotation="0 30 0"
        animation__mouseup="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: red; to: blue; startEvents: mouseup; dur: 5000"
        animation__mousedown="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: blue; to: red; startEvents: mousedown; dur: 5000"
      >
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```